# Parse Login With Username Error

Tags: swift, parse-platform

When I try to login with username I receive an error like "invalid login parameters" however, I am sure that there is a user with this information ?
What is my mistake ?

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("ayakut", password:"1234") {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        println(user)
        if user != nil {
        } else {
            // The login failed. Check error to see why.
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the exact message provided by the error parameter?

Comment: Have you supplied the proper parse app/client keys on launch as well?

Answer (score 1):

Has the User signed up, I know silly question but sometimes parse may had an error when you were signing up so you user may have not been processed! To check this go into your Parse account -> Select the App -> Go to Core -> In Core there should be a class called 'User' check to see If the User was stored or if you have the incorrect credentials!